# Youtube video quality from PHP API using video ID

Tags: php, api, youtube

I've uploaded lots of different videos to Youtube over the past several years and as time has moved on the quality has moved from 320p up to 720p.

As these have been uploaded i've added the youtube video ID to my database and use this to embed each video in an iframe on my site.

However, older videos (the 320p ones) are being embedded in an IFRAME that are far too big for them and look really poor quality.

I therefore need a way to identify the size on each video using its ID in PHP using the API and sizing the IFRAME appropriately.

Has anybody tried doing this? I've been struggling for hours now and the documentation is useless.

Comment: You shouldn't resize it using PHP. Use JavaScript! By using JavaScript you will also be able to scale the iframe properly when resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `&vq=hd720` (720 is resolution, you can change it) at the end of the URL, so you can identify the resolution.

Comment: This doesn't extract info about the video from youtube, it simply pulls the resource at 720p quality which isnt what I require.